# string.split returns a string[] I want a List<string> is there a one liner to convert an array to a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, list

Lists in C# have the `.ToArray()` method. I want the inverse, where an array is transformed into a list. I know how to create a list and loop through it but I would like a one liner to swap it back.

I am using the `String.Split` method in the .NET 2.0 environment, so LINQ, etc. is not available to me.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
string s = ...
new List<string>(s.Split(....));
```

Comment: You want to be careful here to use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries or you may end up with a list with a single empty string instead of a list with no elements when the string is the empty string.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: True, but it is the same without having the results in a List, so it depends on what he needs from the split function, and not how the data is stored.

Comment: Just wanted to mention it since there is a semantic difference between an empty List and a List with one empty element.

Comment: So, in your example, we would never be able to use said list, as it has no reference name...

Answer (score 17):

In .Net 3.5, the `System.Linq` namespace includes an extension method called `ToList<>()`.

Answer (score 7):

```
return new List<string>(stringArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is an object that implements the IList interface and you do not need to add new items you might also do it like this:

```
IList<string> list = myString.Split(' ');
```